# Override Woocommerce checkout fields label

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to override/translate the woocommerce checkout field labels. I've tried in different ways but unfortunately the labels remain unchanged.

I've tried  using this codes:
1)

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields');
function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['label'] = __('Adresa Email', "woocommerce");
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['label'] = __('Telefon', "woocommerce");
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = __('Adauga un mesaj suplimentar, daca doresti sa specifici anumite detalii. Adauga detalii.', "woocommerce");
    return $fields;
}
```

2. 

```
function translate_textes( $translated, $untranslated, $domain ) {
 
   if ( ! is_admin() && 'woocommerce' === $domain ) {
 
      switch ( $untranslated ) {
 
        case 'Phone ' :
 
            $translated = 'Telefon';
            break;
              
    case 'Email Address ' :
 
            $translated = 'Adresa Email';
            break;


        case 'Order notes ' :
 
            $translated = 'Adauga un mesaj suplimentar.';
            break;  
              

      }
 
   }   
  
   return $translated;
 
}

add_filter( 'gettext', 'translate_textes', 999, 3 );
```

3. I've translated all the textes using Loco Translate.

Unfortunately nothing worked :(

Comment: This is `add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields');` working fine.

Comment: Unfortunately for me it doesn't work. The labels are the same.

Comment: change the filter priority and check `add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields', 1);`

Comment: Still doesn't work :(